# Sublime Text 4 editing code, showing a procedure in a new view

Tags: sublimetext

Whilst editing some code (Python in my case), a local procedure name can be right-clicked and goto definition chosen.  Is it possible to have the procedure displayed in a new view beside the current view?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior when using the [`LSP`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) package, in conjunction with a [Python-specific language server](https://packagecontrol.io/search/lsp%20python). I use [`LSP-pyright`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-pyright), which is the server Microsoft uses by default in VS Code, but [`LSP-pylsp`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-pylsp) is also a good option.

When you mouse over an identifier, whether it's a variable or a function, a small window (called a phantom) pops up with several links, the first one being "Definition". Click on that and a new view will open up with the source file containing the function's definition.